# How to validate PHP variable names like $as['abc'] in a HTML textbox

Tags: php, javascript, validation

I am trying to validate a user input PHP variable name like `$as_cap['abc']` at insert time.

I have to check whether the variable name format is right or wrong. Please help me on that. 
Curr
ently I use

```
eregi("^[a-z0-9_.'-]{1,50}$")
```

but it's not working.

Comment: It doesn't work because you forgot to include `[`, `]` and `$` chars

Comment: You tagged it JavaScript - do you want to do it on the client too?

Comment: What do you want to validate  for exactly?

Comment: @zerkms - so how can i include [,] and $ plz, tell me...

Comment: add `\]\[\$` to your character class

Comment: @Pekka  - i have a one form in that form i have to take user defined variable name input..and that variable may be array varibale or simple variable

Comment: Why do you need to validate variable names? **Variables are inner things of the program and users should never be in touch with them**. NEVER.

Comment: @ Col. Shrapne but here i have to build module which manage all this variables...admin programmer can add variable, edit variable value etc...

Comment: @zerkms ..you mean like this...eregi("^[a-z0-9_.'[\[\]-]{1,50}$") ?

Comment: @ravi that's impossible. no site user can manage program variables. You can manage some settings or values, not variable. you're certainly doing something wrong

Comment: @ Col. Shrapne ...here the main thing behaind this module is language translation.....where variable names remain same but only its value changed in different language

Comment: @ravi that is likely to be a bad idea architecturally: You would usually have a variable name or placeholder in *one* language (like `button_cancel`) and fill the variable with the translated text.

Comment: `eregi()` (and the entire ereg family of functions) are deprecated. Switch over to the equivalent `preg_*()` family now, to save yourself pain later on.

Comment: @Marc B ohk...thanx buddy... can you give me one example on this.....

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php

Answer (score 0):

regexp that matches your example and its use in javascript:

```
var checkResult = inputText.match(/\$[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*\[[a-z\']+\]/);
```

You'll probably need to add global flags and adjust it a bit in case you're using text area and there can be more occurrences of searched assignments

Comment: hi thanx for your reply,,but can i used fuction like eregi("^[a-z0-9_.'[\[\]-]{1,50}$" but its not working yet..